# Bootstrap accordion collapse with th:block

Tags: java, html, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

Hello i have a problem with print objects on website. I have a packets from DB and i want print them in to the Accordion collapse (example on Boostrap).
Now i have all objects or any objects open on the website.

```
    <div id="accordion">
    <th:block th:each="packet: ${packet}">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-controls="collapse" th:text="${packet.name}">
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading" data-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body" th:text="${packet.description}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </th:block>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with the css classes you are using inside the block. Use `show` only to show the card you want and you have to use `collapsed` in the buttons inside collapsed cards. The following code will show all the items collapsed:

```
  <div id="accordion">
    <th:block th:each="packet: ${packet}">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-controls="collapse" th:text="${packet.name}">
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading" data-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body" th:text="${packet.description}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </th:block>
    </div>
```